# What holiday scene does the jawa unlock?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

One of the '?' characters in the Holiday Update is a jawa. What scene does he unlock?

Comment: Your question didn't meet quality standards because you're a new user posting a question that contains 17 words, with a title that isn't a question.

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure my next q does those things.  And I see why it's a duplicate too - the other post does have the jawa going to the droid store.  The post goes longer than I could tell on my phone.

Answer (score 4):

The jawa ? character is not new to the holiday update.  To my knowledge, no one has reported it unlocking any specific scene.